# Universal apps TextBlockButtonStyle

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, generic.xaml

I am moving my WinRT 8.1 page to the shared project (universal app). Yet the style "TextBlockButtonStyle" gives an exception in the WP8.1 app. Is it not available for the WP8.1? If not, is there a list that gives a clue what's common style and what's not?

Thanks,

Zhao Min

Comment: Why not just look at the generic.xaml for WP8.1 to see all the listed default styles?

Comment: Yeah, i've checked, it's not there... This is quite annoying... Maybe I'll just use TextBlock and an interactivity click event.

Comment: Well you can add it yourself, it's pretty easy.  Check solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the Style in yourself.

In **App.xaml**

---

```
<Application.Resources>    
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Text" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                        <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ApplicationSecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

---

Now you can just do

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Content="Button 1" Height="200" Width="200"></Button>`
```

Remember it will be in the "Local Resources" instead of the System Resources

[image]